# SVN/Trac - OPTIONS reponse did not include requested activity collection set

Tags: svn, fedora, trac

We have a trac server on our network, and when I run the following:

```
svn co http://trac.theserver.com/browser/trunk/thefolder .
```

Then I put in my LDAP password, and I get this

```
svn: The OPTIONS response did not include the requested activity-collection-set; this often means that the URL is not WebDAV-enabled
```

What do I need to do to resolve this?  The previous IT guy had all sorts of weird ways of setting up stuff on the network.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trac does not serve subversion repositories in proper way to be consumed by subversion client (ex. webdav).

Trac is a webapplication for project managment, and the browser part is there for to interactively browse the repositry with a webbrowser.

For a checkout you must know the url to subversion, where it is served via webdav (maybe: http://svn.theserver.com/trunk/thefolder ?)